# C# xUnit test actual values returned are empty

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, dapper, xunit

I'm trying to write unit test using `xUnit` for `EntityService` class which is using `Dapper` to get data from `Sqllite` database. In my unit test it always returns actual values as `List<Entity> []` and test fails. I'm not understanding what I am missing here.

**Test Class**

```
public class EntityServiceTests
{
    private readonly IEntityService _sut;
    private readonly Mock<IEntityService> _entityServiceMock;

    public EntityServiceTests()
    {
        _entityServiceMock = new Mock<IEntityService>();

        var dapperMock = new Mock<IDapperWrapper>();
        _sut = new EntityService(dapperMock.Object);
    }

    [Fact]
    public void GetEntities_ShouldReturnEntities()
    {
        //Arrange
        var expectedEntities = new List<Entity>
        {
            new()
            {
                Id = 1,
                Name = "Test",
                X = 12,
                Y = 14.5,
                CoordId = 1
            },
            new()
            {
                Id = 2,
                Name = "Test2",
                X = 16,
                Y = 18.5,
                CoordId = 2
            }
        };

        var query = @"SELECT ent.*, crd.x, crd.y, crd.id as CoordId 
                            FROM entities ent 
                            INNER JOIN coords crd ON crd.entityId = ent.Id";

        _entityServiceMock.Setup(x => x.GetEntities(0)).Returns(expectedEntities);

        //Act
        var entities = _sut.GetEntities(0).ToList();

        //Assert

        Assert.Equal(expectedEntities, entities);
    }
}
```

**Service Class**

```
public class EntityService : IEntityService
{
    private readonly IDapperWrapper _dapperWrapper;

    public EntityService(IDapperWrapper dapperWrapper)
    {
        _dapperWrapper = dapperWrapper;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Entity> GetEntities(int entityId)
    {
        var query = @"SELECT ent.*, crd.x, crd.y, crd.id as CoordId 
                            FROM entities ent 
                            INNER JOIN coords crd ON crd.entityId = ent.Id ";
        if (entityId > 0)
        {
            query += " WHERE ent.id = @id";

            var entities = _dapperWrapper.Query<Entity>(query, new { id = entityId });
            return entities;
        }
        else
        {
            var entities = _dapperWrapper.Query<Entity>(query);

            return entities;
        }
    }
}
```

**Dapper Wrapper Class**

```
public class DapperWrapper : IDapperWrapper
{
    private IDbConnection Connection { get; }

    public DapperWrapper()
    {
        Connection = new SQLiteConnection(GetConnectionString("ConnectionString"));
    }

    private string GetConnectionString(string name)
    {
        return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[name].ConnectionString;
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> Query<T>(string query)
    {
        return Connection.Query<T>(query);
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> Query<T>(string query, object param)
    {
        return Connection.Query<T>(query, param);
    }

    public T QuerySingle<T>(string query, object param)
    {
        return Connection.QuerySingle<T>(query, param);
    }
}
```

[image: Unit test result]

Normally the project is working fine. but in Test it fails. I think i'm missing something very basic but crucial.

**UPDATE: I'm using this code now but still getting failed result**

```
    [Fact]
    public void GetEntities_Should_Return_All_Entities_If_0_Is_Provided_In_Param()
    {
        //Arrange
        var expectedEntities = new List<Entity>
        {
            new()
            {
                Id = 1,
                Name = "Test",
                X = 12,
                Y = 14.5,
                CoordId = 1
            },
            new()
            {
                Id = 2,
                Name = "Test2",
                X = 16,
                Y = 18.5,
                CoordId = 2
            }
        };

        var query = @"SELECT ent.*, crd.x, crd.y, crd.id as CoordId 
                        FROM entities ent 
                        INNER JOIN coords crd ON crd.entityId = ent.Id ";

        var dapperMock = new Mock<IDapperWrapper>();
        dapperMock.Setup(x => x.Query<Entity>(query)).Returns(expectedEntities);
        var sut = new EntityService(dapperMock.Object);

        //Act
        var entities = sut.GetEntities(0);

        //Assert
        Assert.Equal(expectedEntities, entities);
    }
```

Comment: You are not using _entityServiceMock, so why bother setting it up. And you are calling GetEntities on _sut, which is not using you expectedEntities in anyway. I don't see why you expect it to work.

Comment: And if you should "fix" the test, it has no value, because you not really testing anything but your test code.

Comment: @PalleDue  `_entityServiceMock.Setup(x => x.GetEntities(0)).Returns(expectedEntities);` I'm using it here to setup mock and expected values.

Comment: You are setting it up, you are not using it. Your EntityService only uses the dapperWrapper mock.

Comment: @PalleDue I've updated the code still getting same error. Please check.

Comment: I guess your setup should be: `dapperMock.Setup(x => x.Query<Entity>(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(expectedEntities);`As I understand Moq you are setting it up to only return if the exact string reference query is used. But your test is still of very little value.

Comment: I forgot the 0 in the comment above: `dapperMock.Setup(x => x.Query<Entity>(It.IsAny<string>(), 0)).Returns(expectedEntities);`

Comment: @PalleDue Same result. Actual Values returned are empty as before !

Comment: Problem is not with mock it works when i debug problem is this line `var entities = sut.GetEntities(0);` when i debug i see i run everything fine when query executes it returns none. i can't understand why...

Answer (score 2):

> I think i'm missing something very basic but crucial.

Indeed  mocking is intended to be used to mock away the dependencies from a unit to test (`sut`). In your case your unit to test is the `EntityService` and the dependency to mock away is `IDapperWrapper`.
But instead of only mocking the dependency, you're mocking the SUT as well with `_entityServiceMock`.

So you COULD try to do it like this within your test:

```cs
public class EntityServiceTests
{
    [Fact]
    public void GetEntities_ShouldReturnEntities()
    {
        //Arrange
        var expectedEntities = new List<Entity>
        {
            new()
            {
                Id = 1,
                Name = "Test",
                X = 12,
                Y = 14.5,
                CoordId = 1
            }
        };

        var query = @"SELECT ent.*, crd.x, crd.y, crd.id as CoordId 
                            FROM entities ent 
                            INNER JOIN coords crd ON crd.entityId = ent.Id WHERE ent.id = @id";
        var dapperMock = new Mock<IDapperWrapper>();
        dapperMock.Setup(x => x.Query<Entity>(query, 1)).Returns(expectedEntities.First());
        var sut = new EntityService(dapperMock.Object);

        //Act
        var entities = sut.GetEntities(1).ToList();

        //Assert
        Assert.Equal(expectedEntities, entities);
    }
}
```

But I highly discourage you from doing so because you'll end up mocking all the Dapper stuff.

Instead you better use an in-memory database (like SQLite), use a real Dapper instance. This way your tests will become much more comprehensive, shorter and business-facing. [This blog post](https://mikhail.io/2016/02/unit-testing-dapper-repositories/) should give you a good starting point.

Comment: I'm still getting the same result. Actual Entities returned are empty. and test fails. I've updated question with your changes please check.

Comment: Yes of course, because in your code `expectedEntities` only contains an object with `Id = 1`, but `dapperMock` is configured for `Id = 0`

Comment: dapper is configured to return all. because if 0 id is provided then Where clause is not attached. Anyway, with 1 id provided still same result is returned. Because problem is it just doesnt contain any result to assert. Actual Result value is empty list.

Comment: That's exactly why I discourage using this pattern: you're spending a lot of time with almost no value. Use an in-memory database instead with a real Dapper instance and you'll be happy

Comment: for now i don't have any other option and it's just not working idk why :(